# i cant order/move k2 items in joomla 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0, k2

I'm facing some issues in joomla 3.0 backend in k2 component several buttons don’t have actions, I can't reorder any item because in the move to reorder all get stuck, i think maybe is a javascipt conflict using multiple Jquery UI libraries?

Comment: Your question lacks any useful information. Please clarify what your issue is.

Comment: There is a site at http://www.jomla.stackexchange.com that will understand what you are asking. I would be almost certain you have a javascript error that is breaking functionality. Check your javascript console or use firebug to see the error.

Comment: it's http://joomla.stackexchange.com/, not jomla

Comment: Thanks for the info, i will seach and post in joomla.stackexchange